# Add text to plots created with a function in r

Tags: r, function, text, plot

I create a figure containing two plots using a function i.e.

```
data1<-1:3

basic<-function(data1){
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(data1)
plot(data1)
}

basic(data1)
```

Now I want to add text to the plots without having to include it in the function. But I can only add text to the bottom plot (see below).

```
text(x=c(1.5,1.6,1.7),y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("X","Y","Z"))
```

[image]

How can I add text to the top plot outside of the function? (I have lots of figures I create using the same function but need to place slightly different text labels in slightly different positions on each one). Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The moment you call plot you switch the focus to the second plot. Simply add your `text()` before the call to the second plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could outline what the different texts are first e.g.

```
data1<-1:3

text1 <- data.frame(x=c(1.5,1.6,1.7),y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("X","Y","Z"))
text2 <- data.frame(x=c(2,2.9,1.0),y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("X","Y","Z"))
```

then put them in your function

```
basic<-function(data1){
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(data1)
text(text1)
plot(data1)
text(text2)
}

basic(data1)
```

As @Andrie says calling plot means any further `text()` calls will work on the last plot only

[image]

Comment: Hmm... so there is no real way of getting around the fact that I need to add the text within the function. Then agina this shouldn't be that difficult if I use data.frames as you suggested...maybe just a bit fiddly. Thanks!

Comment: @Elizabeth why not include another argument in your function that will pass on title to a specific plot?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you can use function `split.screen` instead of `par(mfrow=...)` or `layout`.

```
split.screen(c(2,1)) # Two rows of plots, one column.
```

You can then switch from one "screen" to the other using function `screen`.  See `?split.screen` for more information.

In your example that gives the following:

```
basic <- function(data1){
    split.screen(c(2,1))
    screen(1)
    plot(data1)
    screen(2)
    plot(data1)
    }

basic(data1)
screen(1, new=FALSE)
text(x=c(1.5,1.6,1.7),y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("X","Y","Z"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it using the `par` command:

```
data1 <- 1:3

basic <- function(data1) {
    out <- list()
    par(mfrow=c(2,1))

    plot(data1)
    out[[1]] <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)

    plot(data1)
    out[[2]] <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)

    invisible(out)
}

pars <- basic(data1)


par(pars[[1]])
par(mfg=c(1,1))
text( x=c(1.5,1.6,1.7), y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("X","Y","Z") )

par(pars[[2]])
par(mfg=c(2,1))
text( x=c(1.5,1.6,1.7), y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("A","B","C") )

par(pars[[1]])
par(mfg=c(1,1))
text( x=c(1.7,1.6,1.5), y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("X","Y","Z") )

par(pars[[2]])
par(mfg=c(2,1))
text( x=c(1.7,1.6,1.5), y=c(2,2.1,2.2), labels=c("A","B","C") )
```

Comment: +1 brilliant! I knew there was a `par` parameter that was doing this but couldn't find it back.