# Adjust graph done in R

Tags: r, graph

I would like help with my graph. I generated a graph, but I would like to insert IdealPoint and SolutionFinal together with the graph. I didn't insert all the code, because it's really big. Unfortunately, I was unable to make executable code, but I believe I don't have to for this case.
I would just like someone to help me insert these two (IdealPoint and SolutionFinal) in the graph.

Could you help me solve it ??

Thank you very much!

Best Regards.

```
.
if(Filter2==1 & s[1]>0){
  Mean<-subset(mean, mean[,1] <=s[1])
} else{Mean<-mean}

Mean<-Mean[,2:3]

IdealPoint<-as.matrix(t(c(min(Mean[,1]),max(Mean[,2]))))
aux_solution<-as.matrix(dist(rbind(Mean,IdealPoint)))
IdealPoint

distancia_solution<-min(aux_solution[as.matrix(dim(Mean))[1,1]+1,1:as.matrix(dim(Mean))[1,1]])
a<-which(aux_solution[dim(Mean)[1]+1,]==distancia_solution)
SolutionFinal<-Mean[a[1],]
SolutionFinal

plot(Mean[,1],Mean[,2],xlab="Range of Coverage", ylab="Minimal waste")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can't check this ahead of time, but you should be able to just use the function `points()` to add other points.

So something like

```
plot(Mean[,1],Mean[,2],xlab="Range of Coverage", ylab="Minimal waste")
points(IdealPoint[,1],IdealPoint[,2])
points(SolutionFinal[,1],SolutionFinal[,2])
```

---

EDIT

If you change the last line to

```
points(SolutionFinal[1],SolutionFinal[2])
```

Then it does work. But the problem is that it is stacking all the points. So `SolutionFinal[1],SolutionFinal[2]` is the same as `IdealPoint[,1],IdealPoint[,2]` and the top-left point in your plot.

You can see them if you jitter the points a bit with `jitter`

```
plot(jitter(Mean[,1],1.5),Mean[,2],xlab="Range of Coverage", ylab="Minimal waste")
points(jitter(IdealPoint[,1],1.5),IdealPoint[,2],col="red")
points(jitter(SolutionFinal[1],1.5),jitter(SolutionFinal[2],1.5),col="purple")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it didn't work. I now insert executable code for you to test.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @JSouza see edits and let me know if this solves it

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan! It worked, one more thing, if you know, I would like to insert the respective names IdealPoint and SolutionFinal near the points, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with the function `text()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491933/add-text-to-plots-created-with-a-function-in-r. Also, do not forget to accept this answer as correct if it answered your question. It will let the community know that you've received a solution to your problem and aren't looking for a different one.